# Getting an irreducible polynomial from co-prime polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f$, $g$ both in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$ be 2 relatively prime polynomials with $\deg(f) > \deg(g)$. I need to show that for every sufficiently large prime $p$, the polynomial $pf+g$ is irreducible.
I tried divisibility criteria but even with simple cases, I didn't succeed, so I think it must be something else.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/IrredCrit1.pdf